# Where is 'behavior' in 21.10 Files preferences?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I need to enable 'run' for executable text files, this option should be in the behavior tab in files preferences but the tab itself isn't there. There's like a couple ux options and that's it.

Comment: DO NOT reedit your posts to add inflammatory ranting and disdain into your posts.  This results in content locking like I just instituted.  Ask Ubuntu is not where to take out your frustrations.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the "Allow executing file as program" setting in Files (a.k.a Nautilus)?

[image: Allow executing]

In the event you don't see this, you can always set a file as executable via Terminal, as asinine as it may seem, with the following command:

```
sudo chmod +x {file name}
```

<sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{file name}` with the file's name.</sup>